# How to check length of protocols

Tags: wireshark

How to check exact length of each protocol in wireshark...
1) IP
2) TCP
3) UDP
4) HTTP
5) TCP or UDP Port is 80
6) No ARP or DNS
7) RTP
Please explain in detail; is there any document which talks about how to check/calculate length of each packet.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, field named `frame.len` is the size of the frame as seen "on the wire" ([source](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/f/frame.html)).

You can find specifications of each protocol in relevant RFCs.